# Series of Analytic Functions is Analytic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, power-series, analytic-functions

Let $0 \in \mathbf{N}$. Let $P_m(x): [0,1] \to \mathbf{C}$ be bounded analytic functions for every $m\in \mathbf{N}$. Formally, define
$$
f(x) = \sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_m P_m(x)\overline{P_m}(x),
$$
where
$
\overline{P_m}(x)
$
is the complex conjugate of $P_m(x)$.

**Conjecture.** There exist coefficients $c_m > 0$ such that $f$ is also analytic in $[0,1]$. Furthermore,
$$
f^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_m \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(P_m(x)\overline{P_m}(x)\right).
$$

**Ideas.** It is my understanding that since $P_m$ is analytic, then $\overline{P_m}$ is also analytic. Additionally, the product of two analytic functions is also analytic. Hence, $P_m(x)\overline{P_m}(x)$ is also analytic. So, it suffices to prove that an absolutely convergent series of analytic functions is itself analytic. For sake of notation, let $q_m(x) = P_m(x)\overline{P_m}(x)$. As $q_m$ is analytic, we have that
$$
q_m(x) = \sum_{n\in \mathbf{N}}d_{mn} x^n
$$
for some coefficients $d_{mm}$. So, we have
$$
f(x) = \sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_m P_m(x)\overline{P_m}(x) = \sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_m \sum_{n\in \mathbf{N}}d_{mn} x^n.
$$
Therefore, if
$$
\sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}\sum_{n\in \mathbf{N}}|c_md_{mn}| < \infty,
$$
then $f$ would be analytic as that would allow us to change the order of summation. As $q_m$ is analytic, its power series is absolutely convergent. Hence,
$$
\sum_{n\in \mathbf{N}}|d_{mn}| < M_{m} < \infty.
$$
Therefore, let
$$
c_m = \frac{1}{2^m M_m}. 
$$
Thus,
$$
\sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}\sum_{n\in \mathbf{N}}|c_md_{mn}| < \infty,
$$
and
$$
f(x) = \sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_m P_m(x)\overline{P_m}(x) = \sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_m \sum_{n\in \mathbf{N}}d_{mn} x^n = \sum_{n\in \mathbf{N}}\left(\sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_md_{mn}\right)x^n,
$$
implying $f$ is analytic.

**Questions.** Does the prior argument work? Did I make any glaring mistakes? Also, I'm quite stuck on showing that the summation and differentiation commute in this instance. I believe it suffices in showing that
$$
\sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_m \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(P_m(x)\overline{P_m}(x)\right)
$$
converges uniformly. Does this immediately follow from the assumptions that the $P_m$ functions are analytic hence continuous. And from the fact that
$$
\sum_{m\in \mathbf{N}}c_m \left|\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(P_m(x)\overline{P_m}(x)\right)\right|
$$
is continous for all $n$. Or does that not hold. Any advice or counterexamples would be appreciated.

Comment: This is very confusing. "Entire" means that the function is analytic on the domain $\Bbb C$, but you've written the domain as $[0,1]$. Does the bar mean complex conjugation? because the complex conjugate of an analytic function is not analytic. You first say to choose (fix) coefficients $c_m$, but then claim that there exist coefficients $c_m$.

Comment: It is poorly worded. My specific problem has the $P_m$ functions being finite sums of complex exponentials with their domains being $[0,1]$. It is my understanding that these finite sums are entire and so their restriction will also be analytic. The bar is complex conjugation. My main question is can we find coefficients to make the $f$ function analytic. It is clear that we can find coefficients such that the series converges absolutely.

Comment: I have replaced "entire" with analytic to be correct.

Comment: I think there is a little confusion here with the notion of analytic as it seems you assume that $P_m$ are real analytic (meaning here their real and imaginary parts are analytic as real functions of a real variable) and then the conjugate is indeed real analytic too, but it is not the conjugate in the extension to complex analytic functions on a neighborhood of $[0,1]$ sense - for example if $f(x)=e^{ix}$ its conjugate is $g(x)=e^{-ix}$ but the extensions are $e^{iz}$ and $e^{-iz}$ which are in general not conjugate; the result then follows as in the complex case

Comment: of course all with the caveat that the extension to complex analytic functions has to be done carefully - for example if $f(x)=ix$ so the conjugate is $-ix$ on the reals the product is $|x|^2=x^2$ and its extension is $z^2$ not $|z|^2$ etc - in other words if you restrict yourself to real analytic functions on $[0,1]$ (meaning complex functions of a real variable which are analytic in the real sense) you are good, but if you want to extend the results to complex domains you have to be really careful

Comment: @Conrad Are you saying I'm good with my proof sketch showing that $f$ is also real analytic on $[0,1]$ or are you saying that the complex conjugate of real analytic functions is also real analytic?

Comment: Both - your sketch is correct and is essentially one way of proving the result with power series convergence properties (you can also give a complex analytic proof with care as noted above by taking the complex analytic extension of the conjugate which is NOT the conjugate of the original function outside the reals but indeed exists as real analyticity is preserved under conjugation)

Comment: @Conrad Does differentiation and summation also commute for this $f$ function since the $P_m$ functions are well behaved?

Comment: Yes - same as for usual (complex) analytic functions - one can use power series theory since the derivative coefficients multiply by $n$ so are same exponential size as the original (so $|n a_n| r^n$ go inverse exponentially to zero for $r$ smaller than convergence radius) or complex integration methods using the holomorphic extension to a complex domain